# How can I use jquery addClass/removeClass functionality in AngularJS using ng-class and ng-click?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have two `divs` that I'm trying to switch into an active inactive state, changing `class`, and I need to use `ng-click` with `ng-class`.  This basic code snippet is perfect for what I need, but I'm not sure how it's supposed to translate with `ng-click` and `ng-class` in the `controller`.

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
$('button').removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
```

I pretty much have to use `ng-click` and `ng-class` to do this (don't ask).  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
<button ng-click="selected=!selected">button</button>
<div ng-class="{selected: selected}">div</div>
```